# java manifest link to jar in parent directory

Tags: java

I'm trying to link to an external jar in MANIFEST.MF. This is what my file structure looks like.

```
Jar1.jar
Main.jar
|-META-INF
  |-MANIFEST.MF
```

I want Main.jar to include Jar1.jar from within MANIFEST.MF.

I tried:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: ../../Jar1.jar
```

Doesn't seem to work. How would I link this?

Comment: Jar1.jar and Main.jar are in the same directory. So the Class-Path should just be `Jar1.jar`.

Comment: This is documented in the official tutorial about jar files, BTW. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html